# Return Timespan ticks difference in LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq

I'm querying a list of objects, and I want to return a TimeSpan's ticks list of the difference between the time registered in the object, and now.

I wanted all in one expression, so:

```
var list = (from r in res where r.Site == "CNIS"
    select Math.Abs((r.Timestamp.Value - DateTime.Now).Ticks)).ToList();
```

But I get the following error:

> **Exception Details:** DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type

I already managed to do a workaround. For example, my code looks like this now:

```
var list = new List<long>();
foreach(var item in (from r in res where r.Site == "CNIS" select r))
    list.Add(Math.Abs((item.Timestamp.Value - DateTime.Now).Ticks));
```

But what I really wanted to know is if it is possible to get the Timespan diff from a DateTime value to now, **in a single LINQ query**

Comment: is this linq to objects or EF or SQL ?

Comment: `res` is an `IQueryable<>` of an EF entity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error is relevant to the translation of your select statement into `SQL`.If fecthing the results form `DB` is not a problem you can do it using `AsEnumerable` and then project the items:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var list = res.Where(r => r.Site == "CNIS")
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(x => Math.Abs((x.Timestamp.Value - now).Ticks))
           .ToList();
```

And since the value of `DateTime.Now` changes you should probably store the it into a variable and use it in the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, it works! - Just a note: In the select statement, you're using `item` where it should be `x`. (I know you probably aren't debugging it... no problem. Thanks a lot...)